# Rotas Privada ReactJS e React Router

Tags: javascript, react, jwt, react-router, router

É possível implementar rotas privadas recebendo um token JWT no header e informações no body no ReactJs com o React Router?

Comment: Sim é possível.

Comment: sabe algum link com tutorial ou código de exemplo?

Comment: Então infelizmente não tenho nenhum projeto publico com este conteúdo, mas se não me engano no canal da [Rocketseat](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSfwM5u0Kce6Cce8_S72olg) vai ter algum conteúdo próximo disso.

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo dessa forma nas minhas aplica

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
return (

    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        isAuth() ?
            <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to="/signIn" />
    )} />
);
};
```

Esse isAuth() é um metódo que vem de um arquivo que eu utilizo pra ver se esta no localstorage

```
module.exports = {
isAuth(){
    var user = localStorage.getItem('current_user')
    if(!user)
        return false

    return true
}
}
```

E no seu arquivo de rotas só você utilizar o Private route quando quiser ter uma rota autenticada

```
<PrivateRoute path="/suaRota" component={ SeuComponent } />
```